# try-with behavior with implicit and explicit closeables

Tags: java, stream

Are the following try-with blocks similar? Will the `dataSocket.getOutputStream()` be closed in both cases?

a)

```
try (Socket dataSocket = new Socket(...);
         OutputStream socketStream = dataSocket.getOutputStream();
         BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socketStream)
         ) {.....}
```

b)

```
try (Socket dataSocket = new Socket(...);
         BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(dataSocket.getOutputStream())
         ) {.....}
```

Note. in b) there is no explicit variable for `dataSocket.getOutputStream()`, in a) we have `socketStream`.

Answer (score 1):

According to `BufferedOutputStream` JavaDoc,

> Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.

Closing `outputStream` would close the underlying outputstream. This is also proven in the source code of `BufferedOutputStream`'s close() method.

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be closed in both cases. Even using only Socket sentence, they should be closed. When socket is closed, streams are closed. Anyway, I prefer explicity add Streams declaration on try-with structure.